# create dataframe in for loop using dataframe array

Tags: r

I'm having a dataframe as like below. I need to extract df based on the region which is availabe in RL

```
    >avg_data
    region  SN      value
    beta    1       32
    alpha   2       44
    beta    3       55
    beta    4       60
    atp     5       22


    > RL
           V1
    1 beta
    2 alpha
```

That dataframe should be in array something like REGR[beta] which should contain beta related information as like below

```
    region  SN      value
    beta    1       32
    beta    3       55
    beta    4       60
```

Similarly for REGR[alpha]

```
    region  SN      value
    alpha   2       44
```

So that I can pass REGR as a argument for plotting graph.

```
    REGR <- data.frame()

    for (i in levels(RL$V1)){
     REGR[i,] <- avg_data[avg_data$region==i, ];
    }
```

I did some mistake in the above code. Please correct me.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` function may be of interest to you. From the help page, split `divides the data in the vector x into the groups defined by f`.

So for your data, it may look something like:

```
> split(avg_data, avg_data$region)
$alpha
  region SN value
2  alpha  2    44

$atp
  region SN value
5    atp  5    22

$beta
  region SN value
1   beta  1    32
3   beta  3    55
4   beta  4    60
```

If you want to filter out the records that do not occur in RL, I'd probably do that in a preprocessing step using the `%in%` function and `[` for extraction:

```
x <- avg_data[avg_data$region %in% RL$V1,]
#-----
  region SN value
1   beta  1    32
2  alpha  2    44
3   beta  3    55
```

That's what I'd feed to `split` if you want to drop atp.

The approach above may be overkill if you are just wanting to plot. Here's an example using `sapply` to iterate through each level of region and make a plot:

```
sapply(unique(x$region), function(z) 
  plot(x[x$region == z,"value"], main=z[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you Very much for this idea of using sapply.